# Adding children in parallel in a ManyToMany Parent-Child relationship with optimistic locking

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency

When using Optimistic Locking with Hibernate; is it possible to allow adding of children in a ManyToMany parent child relationship without increasing the version number of the parent without using `@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)` on the parents side?

There are two entities in this case; Parent and Child. There is a ManyToMany relationship between them, using a JoinTable.

```java
class Parent {

    // ... some code...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "children")
    @OptimisticLock(excluded = true) // Is it possible to get rid of this?
    public List<Child> getChildren() {
            return this.children;
        }
    public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
            this.children = children;
        }
}

class Child {

    // ... some code...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinTable(name = "PARENT_CHILD", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "child_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")})
    public List<Parent> getParents() { 
        return this.parents; 
    }
    public void setParents(List<Parent> parents) { 
        this.parents = parents; 
    }
}
```

Without the `@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)` annotation the version number of the parent seems to be still increased, when a child is added, even though the owning side of the relationship is on the side of the children - this version number increment leads to an `OptimisticLockException` in the end.

The goal is to be able to add several children in concurrently without getting an `OptimisticLockException`. This can be achieved by adding the `@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)` annotation to the parent side of the relationship. Is it possible to make this work without this extra annotation?